# How do I clear a form with HAML?

Tags: javascript, haml

I have a haml form with a submit button.  Here is the code:

```
= form_for Comment.new(commentable: resource), url: polymorphic_path([resource, :comments]), remote: true, method: :post, data: { type: "text html" }, html: { rel: "nofocus", class: "new-comment" } do |f|
  .media
    = f.text_area :body, class: 'input-block-level resizable'
        %button.btn.btn-success(type="submit") Post Comment
```

Is there some kind of syntax that HAML uses to clear the form, or is there an event that is thrown that I can use to use `js` to clear the form?  What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: In javascript there is a form `.reset()` function, I'm pretty sure just HAML can't do this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know HAML, but in HTML you can just use

```
<button type="reset">Click me</button>
```

or

```
<input type="reset" value="Click me" />
```

Ref.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type